# Number of distinct rotated strings

Tags: string, algorithm

We have a string **S** and we want to calculate the number of distinct strings that can be formed by rotating the string.

For example :-

**S = "aaaa"** , here it would be 1 string {**"aaaa"**}

**S = "abab"** , here it would be 2 strings {**"abab"** , **"baba"**}

So ,is there an algorithm to solve this in O(|S|) complexity where |S| is the length of string.

Comment: What have you tried? This seems like a fairly easy problem if you make an attempt at it.

Comment: Well , one way I have thought is to rotate the string and store the different strings formed in a set and answer would be the size of set.

Comment: I was thinking that there could be an algorithm which could use the KMP failure funtion.

Comment: Why even store the set? Are the individual states of purpose? Or just the number of them? Why not just count how many times you rotate it?

Comment: do you mean how many times I rotate to get back to the same string ?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn The key here is number of 'distinct' strings.

Comment: @Mod add what you have tried in the main question. Not in the comments.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: yeah, you stop when the current state matches the initial state. If you kept a count, you have your answer.

Comment: @Corey Ogburn But wont the complexity then be O(|S|^2) ?

Comment: No, at most you had to rotate the string S times because when you do, you're guaranteed to have a state that matches the starting state.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn At each step checking whether you have the same stage as initial stage is O(S) complexity.

Comment: You can use rolling hash functions to get an O(|S|) algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suffix trees, baby!

If string is S. Construct the Suffix Tree for SS (S concatenated to S).

Find number of unique substrings of length |S|. The uniqueness you get automatically. For length |S| you might have to change the suffix tree algo a little (to maintain depth info), but is doable.

(Note that the other answer by johnsoe is actually quadratic, or worse, depending on the implementation of Set).

Comment: Thanks for the answer , just asking did you just make this account to answer all suffix trees questions :P

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with rolling hash functions used in the [Rabin-Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).

You can use the rolling hash to update the hash table for all substrings of size |S| (obtained by sliding a |S| window across SS) in constant time (so, O(|S|) in total).

Assuming your string comes from an alphabet of constant size, you can inspect the hash table in constant time to obtain the required metric.

Comment: This seems like it would be easier to code directly in actual practice than the Ukkonen suffix tree algorithm. +1 to both answers in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
public static int uniqueRotations(String phrase){
    Set<String> rotations = new HashSet<String>();
    rotations.add(phrase);
    for(int i = 0; i < phrase.length() - 1; i++){
        phrase = phrase.charAt(phrase.length() - 1) + phrase.substring(0, phrase.length() - 1); 
        rotations.add(phrase);
    }
    return rotations.size();
}
```

Comment: that's definitely not O(|S|)